# Sed insert variable containing UTF8 chars

Tags: bash, sed, utf-8

I am trying to insert a html-directory structure generated by `tree` via `sed` into an existing html file.

Problem: The directory structure contains html tags and non-ASCII chars:

```
<a href="Wiki">Wiki</a><br> ├── <a href="Wiki/Servers/">Servers</a><br> │   ├── <a href="Wiki/Servers/Plesk-Umzug.html">Plesk-Umzug.html</a><br> │   └── <a href="Wiki/Servers/web02.html">web02.html</a><br> ├── <a href="Wiki/SmartHome/">SmartHome</a><br> │   └── <a href="Wiki/SmartHome/Linksamlung/">Linksamlung</a><br> │   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── <a href="Wiki/SmartHome/Linksamlung/Homematic.html">Homematic.html</a><br> │   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; └── <a href="Wiki/SmartHome/Linksamlung/Netzwerk-scripte.html">Netzwerk-scripte.html</a><br> ├── <a href="Wiki/tmp.html">tmp.html</a><br> └── <a href="Wiki/Verwaltung/">Verwaltung</a><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ├── <a href="Wiki/Verwaltung/Bank.html">Bank.html</a><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; └── <a href="Wiki/Verwaltung/Zugangsdaten.html">Zugangsdaten.html</a><br> <br><br> </p>
```

How can I tell `sed` to insert this text into my file?

`sed -i "11i${MENU}" $FILENAME` returns the following error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unknown command:`�'`

**UPDATE**

Added `tr -cd '\11\12\40-\176'` to remove non-ASCII chars. The current problem is the `<` and `>` char in HTML. I suppose I need to escape them?

Error message is

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown command: `<'
```

**SOLUTION**

Re-implementation in python.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any newlines in `$MENU`?  It may be better to insert as a file: `sed -i 11r<(printf %s "$MENU") "$FILENAME"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you ant to insert a line with `sed` before the line number 11, a more clear syntax would be:

```
sed -i "11 i ${MENU}" $FILENAME
```

Also, please share how you save the html tag in your variable, you should use:

```
MENU='you html tag'
sed -i "11 i ${MENU}" $FILENAME
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18841293)

Comment: I beg to differ, seeing how the initial answer lacks info about the code used to parse the html tag and insert it in the file, I pointed out that it would be a good idea to use `'` when storing the aforementioned tag in a variable.